# re-transferring images to a computer

Tags: nikon

i have transferred images from my memory stick from a Nikon Camera to a computer. Now I want to transfer the images a second time. How do I get it to move all the images and not just ones that have not been transferred before?

Comment: Hi Brian.  I know these are pictures, but this is more of a computer question than photography, so not really on-topic here.  Are you using a transfer program like View NX2, or just copy/pasting in Windows?

Comment: I agree this will _really_ depend on the software you're using. Brian, can you elaborate? I think it generally falls under our "software is on topic in the context of photography" guideline, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using some automatic downloading from the computer. Why not try to go a lower level (more technical) and manage them as files? That is possible if you:
- know the location on the hard drive where they are stored on PC
- can see your memory stick/card reader/camera as a browseable drive in My Computer 
(assumed you have Windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use the program you have been using to copy pics to your computer,
just erase the pics you have already copied from your hard drive, then select all the files from the memory stick, (or all of the ones that you need,) and copy or move them to your computer.

Comment: Don't erase them until you verify that the images are still on the memory card. Many programs offer to erase the card for you after importing. If you happened to choose that option after the previous import you'll lose your only copies by erasing them from your computer.